# tflite : is there any way for tflite to handle various shape of input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to use **MTCNN**  for **face detection** in tflite ,it should be avilible for variable input shape like

> `both 1920*1080 or 640*360`

but tflite must set input shape to a certain value ,is there any way to let tflite accept variable input or output shape ?
many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the model architecture supports variable input shape, you should be able to call the `resizeInput` API (Java) or `ResizeInputTensor` API (if you're using C++).

For example, in Java:

```
interpreter.resizeInput(tensor_index, [1, 1920, 1080, 3]);
interpreter.resizeInput(tensor_index, [1, 640, 360, 3]);
```

Note that many network architectures (e.g. MobileNet, Inception, ResNet...etc) don't support variable input shape.

If you're certain the model should support variable input shape and it doesn't work. Please file a Github issue or reply here.